# Swift: Different Sizes of two UIViews

Tags: swift

I have a problem respective to UIView and UIView subclasses.
In my storyboard I add a UIView (width:368 height:552, center horizontally and vertically).
I have connected this UIView to my ViewController:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mapViewOutlet: UIView!
```

The I want to create a object of my own subclass of UIView:

```
 var bounds:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, mapViewOutlet.frame.size.width, mapViewOutlet.frame.size.height)
 self.roomView     = RoomView(frame: bounds, image: testMap)
```

The first parameter of the init method is bounds. There I give the size of mapViewOutlet to the subclass. The image parameter is the green image (you can see this in the attached image).
But now the size of the green image does not fit the size of the gray mapViewOutlet.

The green UiView is generated as follows:

```
    let testFrame : CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,frame.size.width ,frame.size.height)
    var testView : UIView = UIView(frame: testFrame)
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 4, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
    testView.alpha=0.5
    self.addSubview(testView)
```

Does anybody know how they do not fit?

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know the problem.
The sizes are wrong only in the viewDidLoad().
The following code gives the correct values of the width and height.

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  println(self.mapViewOutlet.frame.size)
}
```